# Implement C++11 multipart sending without copying to a single buffer

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, memory-optimization

I am working on a C++11 project and am migrating the underlying communications library used.

The original library allowed sending messages in multiple parts using a `SNDMORE` flag:

```
socket_->send(str_1, SNDMORE);
socket_->send(str_2, SNDMORE); 
socket_->send(str_3); // The last message
```

and receiving them in multiple parts as well:

```
socket_->recv(&msg);
... // do stuff
while(msg.more()) {
    socket_->recv(msg);
... // do stuff
}
```

The new library does not have this functionality, so I ended up creating a `struct` that merges upto 3 strings and then merges and sends, receives and splits them as required.

```
/**
*
* Created helper methods to merge 3 strings into 1 and reverse
* This is a helper to group 3 messages in a single string.
*
**/

struct MultipartSplitMerge {
   #define PADDING 8
   static std::string merge(std::string *s1, std::string *s2, std::string *s3) {
       std::string size_1 = std::to_string((*s1).size()); std::string size_2 = std::to_string((*s2).size()); 
       std::string padded_size_1 = std::string(PADDING - size_1.length(), '0') + size_1;
       std::string padded_size_2 = std::string(PADDING - size_2.length(), '0') + size_2;
       std::string ret_str(padded_size_1 + padded_size_2 + *s1 + *s2 + *s3);
       return ret_str; // Add the size of each piece
   }

   static void split(std::string *s, std::string *o1, std::string *o2, std::string *o3) {
       unsigned int size_1 = std::stoi((*s).substr (0, PADDING));
       unsigned int size_2 = std::stoi((*s).substr (PADDING, PADDING));
       *o1 = (*s).substr(2 * PADDING, size_1); 
       *o2 = (*s).substr(2 * PADDING + size_1, size_2); 
       *o3 = (*s).substr(2 * PADDING + size_1 + size_2);
   }
};
```

Using this splitter/merger, I now send as follows:

```
std::string nullstr(""); // I use this to leave one of the parts empty
socket_->send(MultipartSplitMerge::merge(&h_array, &msg, &nullstr));
```

The receive code now works like this:

```
std::string combined, temp_1, temp_2, temp_3;
socket_->receive(&combined);
MultipartSplitMerge::split(&combined, &temp_1, &temp_2, &temp_3);
```

I'd like to avoid the unnecessary copies if possible, and also general guidelines on improving this code.

Here's the REPL to play with (or [go to source](//repl.it/MFW8)):

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/MFW8/0.js"></script>
```

Currently, we assume that there are 3 or less splits in every communication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use `namespace` if you want a namespace

You use your `struct` only as a way to have `merge` and `split` not in the global namespace (and inlined). That's not necessary. We can just use a `namespace`:

```
namespace MultipartSplitMerge {
    ...
}
```

## Don't use `define` for compile-time constants

You define `PADDING`, but you never undefine it. It's a common word in code, so it's possible that you accidentally break something. Furthermore, it's not in the same namespace as `merge` and `split`, as the preprocessor does not care about `namespace`s.

Instead, use a `static constexpr size_t`:

```
static constexpr size_t PADDING = 8;
```

This has the nice side-effect that `PADDING` has now a type. The compiler can now warn you when you try to compare it to other, signed types.

## Prefer references instead of pointers

Not only are they easier to use, they also are harder to get wrong.

## Use `const` on call-by-reference/-pointer arguments that are not changed

You never change `s1`, `s2` and `s3`, yet you didn't use `const`. We could have changed their values accidentally. A `const` will prevent this:

```
inline std::string merge(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2, const std::string& s3) {
    const std::string size_1 = std::to_string(s1.size()); 
    const std::string size_2 = std::to_string(s2.size()); 
    const std::string padded_size_1 = std::string(PADDING - size_1.length(), '0') + size_1;
    const std::string padded_size_2 = std::string(PADDING - size_2.length(), '0') + size_2;
    const std::string ret_str(padded_size_1 + padded_size_2 + s1 + s2 + s3);
    return ret_str; // Add the size of each piece
}

inline void split(const std::string& s, std::string &o1, std::string &o2, std::string &o3) {
    const unsigned int size_1 = std::stoi(s.substr(0, PADDING));
    const unsigned int size_2 = std::stoi(s.substr(PADDING, PADDING));
    o1 = s.substr(2 * PADDING, size_1); 
    o2 = s.substr(2 * PADDING + size_1, size_2); 
    o3 = s.substr(2 * PADDING + size_1 + size_2);
}
```

Note that all this `inline` annotations are only necessary if your functions will be in a header.

## Don't repeat yourself

You pad your string, but it's a) hard to get and b) repetitive. Write a function to get rid of the duplicate logic:

```
inline std::string pad(size_t size, char padding, const std::string& original) {
    assert(size >= original.size());
    return std::string(size - original.size(), padding) + original;
}

inline std::string pad_size(const std::string& original) {
    return pad(PADDING, '0', std::to_string(original.size()));
}
```

If you find an optimization for `pad` or `pad_size`, `merge` gets optimized for free. And it gets a lot shorter:

```
inline std::string merge(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2, const std::string& s3) {        
    return pad_size(s1) + pad_size(s2) + s1 + s2 + s3;
}
```

## All code at once

Now let us inspect the reviewed and somewhat rewritten code:

```
namespace MultipartSplitMerge {
static constexpr size_t FIXED_FIELD_LENGTH = 8;

// Optional `detail' namespace; shows a user that `pad' and `pad_size'
// are implementation details. Only important in a header-only
// library
namespace detail {
inline std::string pad(size_t size, char padding, const std::string &original) {
    assert(size >= original.size());
    return std::string(size - original.size(), padding) + original;
}

inline std::string pad_size(const std::string & original) {
    return pad(FIXED_FIELD_LENGTH, '0', std::to_string(original.size()));
}
} // namespace detail

inline std::string merge(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2, const std::string& s3) {        
    return detail::pad_size(s1) + detail::pad_size(s2) + s1 + s2 + s3;
}

inline void split(const std::string& s, std::string& o1, std::string& o2, std::string& o3) {
    const unsigned int size_1 = std::stoi(s.substr(0, FIXED_FIELD_LENGTH));
    const unsigned int size_2 = std::stoi(s.substr(FIXED_FIELD_LENGTH, FIXED_FIELD_LENGTH));
    o1 = s.substr(2 * FIXED_FIELD_LENGTH, size_1); 
    o2 = s.substr(2 * FIXED_FIELD_LENGTH + size_1, size_2); 
    o3 = s.substr(2 * FIXED_FIELD_LENGTH + size_1 + size_2);
}
} // namespace MultipartSplitMerge
```

At this point I wouldn't change the code anymore, unless I see via profiling that `split` or `merge` is a bottle-neck.

If you really notice that `merge` is a bottle-neck, you can use `sprintf`, but I *guess* that the compiler should optimize above code.